# Get raster point values for multiple coordinates

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I'm currently working on my thesis. I have 126k REIT properties loaded into QGIS by coordinates.

On top of that I have the the full US FEMA floodzone shapefiles (13GB). However in order to join attributes by location I have to fix the geometries first. However this causes my computer to completely crash...

I also have a server connection with FEMA, however this is a raster layer.

How do I extract the corresponding flood zones attribute by my property coordinates (126k times)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you get an error for invalid geometries when you join by location? Are you using geopackage output from fix geometries? Try exporting the shapefiles to geopackages before fix geometries. And create spatial indexes